# How to get just one field from a reverse reference in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models, `Roundtrip` and `Tour`, and another model called `RoundtripTour` where I can link those two models in a many-to-many fashion. I have made a rest service that returns a `Tour` instance and a list of all `RoundtripTour` instances through a reverse reference, and it works perfectly, but the service returns all fields from the `RoundtripTour` model, and I want to return only the field that references the `Roundtrip` model instance.

These are my models:

```
class Roundtrip(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, verbose_name=_('Code'))
    duration = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Duration'))
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Description'))

class Tour(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Description'))
    is_own = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('Is own tour?'))
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name=_('Code'))

class RoundtripTour(models.Model):
    roundtrip = models.ForeignKey(Roundtrip, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='tours', verbose_name=_('Roundtrip'))
    tour = models.ForeignKey(Tour, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='roundtrips', verbose_name=_('Tour'))
    day = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Day'))
```

This is my serializer:

```
class TourRoundtripsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    roundtrips = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_roundtrips(self, instance):
        queryset = [x.roundtrip for x in instance.roundtrips.all()]
        return RoundtripSerializer(queryset, many=True, context=self.context).data

class Meta:
    model = models.Tour
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'is_own', 'code', 'roundtrips')
```

This is my view:

```
class TourRoundtripsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Tour.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TourRoundtripsSerializer
```

I would like the `roundtrips` reverser reference to return only the field `roundtrip` from the `RoundtripTour` model (`roundtrip` field of `RoundtripTour` model). Is that possible?

I made the changes suggested by @Ykh, but I get an error. This is the traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /es/reservations_manager/roundtrips/1/composition
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 58, in retrieve
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 560, in data
    ret = super(Serializer, self).data
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 262, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 527, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1855, in to_representation
    return method(value)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/Intellibook/ReservationsManagerApp/serializers.py", line 191, in get_hotels
    return HotelSerializer(queryset, many=True).data
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 765, in data
    ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 262, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 683, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 683, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 527, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/IntellibookProject/IntellibookVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 356, in to_representation
    "the serializer." % self.__class__.__name__
AssertionError: `HyperlinkedRelatedField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.
[24/May/2018 14:23:52] "GET /es/reservations_manager/roundtrips/1/composition HTTP/1.1" 500 145268
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class TourRoundtripsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    roundtrips = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_roundtrips(self, instance):
        queryset = [x.roundtrip for x in instance.roundtrips.all()]
        return RoundtripSerializer(queryset, many=True,  context=self.context).data

    class Meta:
        model = models.Tour
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'is_own', 'code', 'roundtrips')
        depth = 1
```

use [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to get whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, but I tried to use this solution in other cases and it works in most of them, but one. Apparently when the model referenced has foreign keys. I get this error: `AssertionError...'HyperlinkedRelatedField' requires the request in the serializer context. Add 'context={'request': request}' when instantiating the serializer`. I don't know what it means.

Comment: change `return RoundtripSerializer(queryset, many=True).data` to `return RoundtripSerializer(queryset, many=True, context=self.context).data`

Comment: Nope, the same error. I expended a big part of the day searching for the solution, but the documentation has no reference. At least I couldn't find it.

Comment: If the error still exist,please post you code in view related to serializer

Comment: I updated the code for the serializer in the body of the question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: print(self.context) in get_roundtrips method  see what is self.context now

Comment: please post full error log,you miss context in somewhere

Comment: I added the traceback to the error in the question body.

Comment: Sorry, @Ykh, I was checking the original one, not the corrected one. It is working now. Thanks so much.